# Sort game objects alphabetically

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort all of the game objects inside games alphabetically I have a function for it and where I am calling it but my button does not appear to do anything onclick the idea is to upon accessing the site nothing is sorted then once you click the button it sorts all games by title alphabetically. I am still new to Javascript any advice  on achieving this better then my current sort function is appreciated. Below are my code snippets for the sort function the event listener and the html implementation.

*edit 1: I have refactored a bit and it is coming back as undefined when the button is clicked. Adding my 2 snippets as I am executing it differently now.

```
   sortAlpha() {
    this.games.sort(function(gameA, gameB){
        if (gameA.title < gameB.title) {
            return -1;

        }
        if (gameA.title > gameB.title){
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
       });
        window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("filter").onclick = sortAlpha;
       }
    }
```

```
<div id="filter">
    <div id="buttons">
        <button onclick="sortAlpha()">Sort Games Alphabetically</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check your console for errors. I suspect you'll find `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined`

Comment: I thought I might get a error but I dont get anything at all.

Comment: `addEventListener('click', this.sortAlpha)` - what does `this` refer to in the code there? I suspect it's `window`, which means `this.sortAlpha` would be `undefined`, thus you never attach an event listener.

Comment: Ah nice catch. I had assumed `sortGames()` was another member method, didn't notice the `function` keyword.

Comment: My click now works but it does not execute my sortAlpha function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some refactoring what was becoming an issue was within the HTML I was calling the function before the data was being rendered causing the function to work on an array of 0 objects altering my button click and adding the event listener to where the rest of them were being initialized resolved the issue. Below is the updated HTML and JS Function that worked for me.

```
<div id="filter">
    <div id="buttons">
        <button id="sort">Sort Games Alphabetically</button>
    </div>


</div>
```

```
   document.getElementById("sort").addEventListener ("click", this.sortAlpha.bind(this));
```

```
        console.log('test')

        this.games.sort(function(gameA, gameB){
        if (gameA.title < gameB.title) {
            return -1;

        }
        if (gameA.title > gameB.title){
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
       });
       console.log(this.games)
       const gamesContainer = document.getElementById('games-content')
       gamesContainer.innerHTML = ""
       this.renderGames()


    }


}
```